# Similar to SQL LIKE statement in Couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

Is this possible in Couchbase??

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%john%'.
```

Seems like I have to use startkey and endkey. But doesn't seem to get the right results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startKey and endKey will allow you to do like "john%". Couchbase does not allow you to do a contains.

If you really need a contains you should use the Elastic Search plugin.

Comment: Can you provide some examples that will work with Couchbase 2.0

Comment: Sorted it out. Thanks for the recommendation. Love the fact that it has good Groovy support.

Comment: @Vipul If my memory helps, I did play around with the elastic search plugin and managed to do contains. In general back in 2013, Couchbase was not as mature as it is now, so I gave up on it for production purposes. If you look at the new stuff they have for 4.1, it has been a lot of new improvements including N1QL, which is a SQL like language for querying. Here's the reference: http://developer.couchbase.com/guides-and-references

Comment: Couchabse 4.5 now has in-build Full Text Search service. By creating FTS index now you are able to search  term `%term%`.

Answer (score 0):

**Couchbase 4.5+ only**

---

Is needed to create a Full Text Index to be able search for substrings.

1. Log in to the Couchbase Web Console, for example,
   http://localhost:8091/.
2. Click **Indexes > Full Text**, then click on the **New Full Text Index** button.
   [image]
3. A form where you can define your new index configuration is displayed.
4. Each index needs a unique name. Type one in, such as"test-index".
   Only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and underscores are allowed
   for index names. Also, the first character must be an alphabetic
   character. Choose a bucket from the drop-down list. There are more
   options, but you can ignore those for now and rely on the default
   values. **Go!** Finally, click the **Create Index** button.
5. You should now see a summary page of your new full text index. The  document count shows how many documents have been indexed so far. You can click on the Refresh button next to the Document Count field in order to see the indexing progress.

See [Couchbase reference](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/fts/full-text-intro.html) for more information

---

**NOTE:** If you don't see `Full text` tab, you have to enable it and setup Full Text Search service (Full Text RAM Quota).